# Regex excluding [about:] pages in firefox

Tags: firefox, regex, stylish

I'm trying to get stylish style sheet to be deactivated on *about:* pages.
I believe the regular expression below should be able to do just that, but firefox seems to be of a different opinion. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

```
@-moz-document regexp("(^(?=(?!about))){1}.*")
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is

```
@-moz-document regexp("^a?!(bout:).*|^[^a].*")
```

However, testing your regex, it works for me in any case. Are you enclosing the rest of the script in braces afterwards?

```
@-moz-document regexp("(^(?=(?!about))){1}.*") {
    /* rest of script */
}
```

If so, you might have the wrong idea about what the `about:` url is matching. This only matches the *page contents* of `about:` pages. Note that any Firefox UI elements that are affected by your style will still be affected (even when you're visiting an `about:` page).

As an aside, it's convenient to use a simple userstyle like [this](https://userstyles.org/styles/1/stylish-test-style) for testing, so your script's behaviour won't complicate things when testing the regex.